# How to replace null values with its own value with combination

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I am working on a query in Oracle. I am using fact table for contract ID and dimension for product and material. I need to have a solution in the query instead of database.

I have an example result output where some of the Contract ID's have null values.

I can not hard code the NULL values because I have lot of other contract ID's in the table.

Each unique contract id have one product ID and each product have multiple materials.
I would like to replace NULL contract ID's with 17270 in combination of the specific product PR000349059 and materials. So that each NULL value for a contract ID replaces it with its own value.

```
select
    fvpo_vpa_id     contract_id,
    dsai_prpr_sap_matnr    product_ID,
    dsai_sp_sap_matnr       material_ID,
    fvpo_quantity           quantity
from vpa_sp right outer join
     PP_SP
     on fvpo_dsai_id = dsai_id
```

[image]

RESUlT:

```
 CONTRACT_ID PRODUCT_ID MATERIAL_ID QUANTITY
    17270   PR000349059 SP000748364 1962898
    17270   PR000349059 SP000748366 2589732
    17270   PR000349059 SP000748370 5565604
            PR000349059 SP000010709 
            PR000349059 SP000748128 
            PR000349059 SP000748130 
            PR000349059 SP000748132 
            PR000349059 SP000748362
```

Comment: Your expected results seem to be the same as your current results.

Comment: you can see contract id is blank where product_id PR000349059 and SP00010709. I need to replace wit 17270 where  product_id PR000349059 and SP00010709

Comment: And what about the other rows with that product_id and different material codes?  Is it always the same value?  If so just use `NVL` to replace `NULL` values with whatever you want.

Comment: actually I am doing a right join to get product id and material but all materials doesnt have contract id. My need is to look up contract id 17270 where we see it empty based on product and material.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your final result should look like? I have a solution for you but want to make sure I'm understanding your expectation correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based upon your edits and comments, I think I understand what you are looking for.  In the case that `CONTRACT_ID` is `NULL`, fill it with the `CONTRACT_ID` from another row with the same `PRODUCT_ID` and a `NOT NULL` `CONTRACT_ID`.  This query will help you achieve that:

```sql
SELECT NVL(fvpo_vpa_id, MIN(fvpo_vpa_id) OVER (PARTITION BY dsai_prpr_sap_matnr)) contract_id,
       dsai_prpr_sap_matnr product_ID,
       dsai_sp_sap_matnr   material_ID,
       fvpo_quantity       quantity
FROM   vpa_sp
RIGHT  OUTER JOIN pp_sp ON fvpo_dsai_id = dsai_id;
```

This will only replace the `CONTRACT_ID` if it is `NULL` and we are able to find another row with the same `PRODUCT_ID` which is populated.  This is based on the assumption that you mentioned that each `CONTRACT_ID` should only have one `PRODUCT_ID`